# Authenticate user with SSL certificate

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, certificate

I'd like to authenticate the users to my website by checking their SSL client certificate information. I'm going to be using an Apache server, and I'd like to check that their certificates authenticate the users as members of certain organizations.

How can I do that?

Comment: I could migrate this to another suitable site on our network, but I feel this question is a wee bit vague. Maybe you could tell us more about what the site is written in which may have a bearing on the solution? Do you mean that you'll be checking that users are members of certain orgs by reading the org data from the client certificate. Can you bulk out the question a bit and provide more relevant information? Thanks.

Comment: @Kev I'm writing the site in Ruby on Rails, and yes, I'm hoping to read the org data from the client certificate, if that's possible.

Comment: This question as it stands was too vague for us to help out with on Server Fault. Take a look at [the Apache documentation on SSL Client Authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol), and if you still have (specific) questions about the server configuration end of things after reviewing that feel free to swing by [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and ask us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

1. Obtain an SSL Certificate for whichever domain you need, this could be the main domain, subdomain, wildcard, etc.  If your going to have multiple subdomains then a wildcard is the way to go.  SSL Certificates can be purchased from most hosting companies, for example 123-reg provide them.
2. Install Certificate on Apache, depending on OS platform this could be via updating httpd.conf or ssl.conf to reference the SSL Certificate, key, pem files, etc.  You will need to modify the various SSLCertificate... directives, take a look at ssl.conf for the example configuration.
3. Setup whatever authentication you require for Apache hosted site, for example, setup the users using htpasswd.
4. End users then need to install the certificate upon first connecting to the https site, this is done client side and may require admin rights to add to client PC.

Most certificate providers give full installation instructions.

Comment: You've got it back to front. He is talking about client authentication.